# biggest possible domain of diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider the function

$$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y) \mapsto (x^2-y^2,2xy).$$

How can I determine a subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as big as possible such that $f|_D$ becomes a diffeomorphism? So $D$ has to be an open set as well as $f(D)$, and $f$ has to be a bijective and continuously differentiable function as well its inverse function.

If I regard $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ as a point in the complex plane, that is $(x+iy) \in \mathbb{C}$, it is clear to me that

$$f(x,y)=(\operatorname{Re}((x+iy)^2),\operatorname{Im}((x+iy)^2)).$$

I reckon, however, that this is just a geometric interpretation and won't help me. I was thinking about polar coordinates, that is to put together some already known diffeomorphisms. But somehow I am stuck :S A hint would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recognizing $f$ as the real version of the complex map $z \mapsto z^2$ is a great idea. It immediately tells you that if $f$ is to be injective on $D$ then $D$ cannot simultaneously contain $z$ and $-z$. This should give you a hint about one maximal $D$ (actually, about all maximal $D$). After choosing such a $D$, you need to find an inverse for $f$, but that'll be easy.